# Refer range from a cell value

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have the code below and I want **D6:D** and **F6:F** to be in a cell. Cell **M83** has **D6:D** and cell **M80** has **F6:F**.

QUESTION: HOW CAN I USE INDIRECT FOR `'Sheet2'!D6:D` & `'Sheet2'!F6:F*1`

```
={"Messages Sent"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(K80), 
 {REGEXEXTRACT(""&'Sheet2'!D6:D, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDIRECT(K80))), 'Sheet2'!F6:F*1}, 2, 0)))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={"Messages Sent"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(K80), 
 {REGEXEXTRACT(""&INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&M83), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDIRECT(K80))), 
  INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&M80)*1}, 2, 0)))}
```